# wpdb->query from table1 check meta data and publish status

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a fairly complex need, which I am not entirely certain of where to start due to my somewhat limited knowledge of WordPress's database structure and everything.. So here's what I have going on.

I have a custom table that would look something like this:

wp_buzzsumo

```
+--------------------------------------+
| id  pageID  title  totalShares  date |
+--------------------------------------+
| 1   25      -      20000        -    |
| 2   29      -      1992         -    |
| 3   25      -      122345       -    |
| 4   27      -      134          -    |
+--------------------------------------+
```

I have a WordPress query that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_buzzsumo ORDER BY totalShares DESC LIMIT 20
```

And then in the loop in PHP where I output the results, I have some statements to check some things.. But now due to the `LIMIT` of `20` in some cases it does not return anything because the top 20 results fail the if statements... So now I need a way to put these statements into the query..

```
if(
    !get_field("hide_trending_bar", $PageID) && 
    !get_field("hide_hashtags_from_trending_bar", $PageID) && 
    get_page($PageID)->post_status == "publish"
  )
```

$PageID would have to match the `pageID` column in the table above.

I need a query something like this I believe.. But I know this isn't quite the right way of doing this..

```
 SELECT * FROM wp_buzzsumo 
 WHERE wp_posts.pageID=wp_buzzsumo.pageID 
 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
 AND (
      wp_posts.meta_key = 'hide_trending_bar'
      AND 
      wp_posts.meta_value = ""
      )
 AND (
      wp_posts.meta_key = 'hide_hashtags_from_trending_bar'
      AND 
      wp_posts.meta_value = ""
      )

 ORDER BY totalShares DESC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: why a custom table why not store in `meta table` if these values are related to some post type (post / pages ). that will give you power to use `meta_query` which will make your task simpler

Comment: I cannot do that because of the nature of what this custom table holds. They are not entirely related to posts at all really, the "posts" are just the parent page that the data is to be displayed on. This database is more or less a custom post type, but for different sorts of data.. There are about 20k rows and counting.

Answer (score 0):

**another approach :-**

```
$pageids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}buzzsumo ORDER BY totalShares DESC LIMIT 20",ARRAY_N);

$args = array(
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'post_status'      => 'page',
    'include'          => $pageids,
    'meta_query'       => array(
        'relationship' => 'AND',
         array(
            'key'      => 'hide_trending_bar',
            'value'    => '',
            'compare'  => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'      => 'hide_hashtags_from_trending_bar',
            'value'    => '',
            'compare'  => '='
        ),

    )
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: The problem is that the content I need to display are not posts, the content is in the `wp_buzzsumo` table.